# Redirect /var/www/html/app/api/* to /var/www/html/api/*

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2.4

I have a frontend app at `/var/www/html/app` and the API for that app is at `/var/www/html/api`. There is a virtual host set up for `/var/www/html/app`, with the name ***example.com***. Now, I want it so what when a user visits ***example.com/api***, it will redirect all requests to `/var/www/html/api`.

Example:
User enters ***http://example.com/api/some/call*** into their browser - instead of the server looking for `/var/www/html/app/api/some/call`, it will look for `/var/www/html/api/some/call`.

What is the best way to get this done? I tried using symbolic links which works for just /api, but not for variable routes after /api. I am thinking I can get it working with mod rewrite, but I am not that familiar with it.

**UPDATE**

Here is the config for example.com in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/app
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    <Directory /var/www/html/app>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Here in the .htaccess file in `/var/www/html/app` (and the same one at `/var/www/html/api)`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you explain the downvote?

Comment: Plaease either add the relevant parts of your config (cleaned from private config data) or add a list of virtual hosts and their document roots and aliases.